# System in a consolewriteline

Tags: c#, console.writeline

I was studying for my test today and I came accross the sentence 
   `System.Console.WriteLine()`;

Could some one tell me what the System stands for cause when I remove it i dont see any diffrence.

Comment: `System` is a namespace. Read MSDN pages about `namespace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The System is the name of the namespace the class Console resides in. You need to give the full name or it won't compile. With one exception: if you have a line `using System;` on top of your file, whenever something cannot be found, a namespace of `System` will be assumed for lookup.

Answer (score 4):

`System` is just the namespace which contains the `Console` type.

You almost certainly have a *using directive* like this in your code:

```
using System;
```

That *imports* every type within the namespace, so you can refer to it by its simple name. Without that directive, you *would* see a difference - `System.Console` would still work, but just `Console` wouldn't, because the compiler wouldn't know which type you meant.

Answer (score 1):

System is a **Namespace**. You will find it in the head of your code.

```
using System;
```

If you remove `using System;`, you will find Console.WriteLine(); can't be complied.

Answer (score 1):

System refers to the main library that contains the fundamental classes  that define commonly-used value and reference data types, events and event handlers, interfaces, attributes, and processing exceptions. And Console type is one of them.
the reason why you are not getting a difference is that it's referenced by default in the top of your class page

Answer (score 1):

The System in System.Console.WriteLine() refers to the System namespace. Therefore, if you're importing System in your code, it's redundant to call the WriteLine method using that namespace.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Just the namespace where `Console.WriteLine()` resides
which is a default import (`using system`)